# Split function not being recognised

Tags: jsp, random, shuffle

I'm trying to **randomly** shuffle an input retrieved from database. So far I'm able to add the retrieved value to the list. Because i want to the shuffle them, I'm trying to split the word into individual letters..Like ['l','i','s','t'] for eg. But the split function doesn't work.
Where am I going wrong?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.*"%>
<%
String vlemail=request.getParameter("lemail");
try
{
String str="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con=null;
con=DriverManager.getConnection(str,"root","");
Statement st=con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery("select pwd from utable where email='"+vlemail+"'");
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList();
while(rs.next())
{

list.add(rs.getString("pwd"));
out.println(list);
List splitlist=list.split("(?!^)");
Collections.shuffle(splitlist);
out.println(splitlist);
}
out.println("Retrieved" );
}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.println(e);
out.println("Not retrieved");
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `list.split("(?!^)");`? Split function can be used to split a string whereas you are trying to use it on ArrayList.

It will be better if you want to use the split function. Even better that you append all the results into a single string, post that split, and then add it to Arraylist according to your requirement. Then, do the shuffle.

Comment: String r=rs.getString("pwd");
  out.println(r);
  String[] p=r.split("");
    out.println(p);
   Arrays.sort(p);
   out.println(p);                                                                                               I ve modified the while part a little bit,but still doesnt work..it prints [Ljava.lang.String;@48a669d8

Comment: 'p' is of array type you cant use print command directly on array , Iterate over it by using any loop for eg: for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++){out.println(p[i]);}

Comment: you got the result you needed ?